# TypeScript Exclude<UnionOfTypes, UnionOfTypes> is type “never”

Tags: typescript, redux

I have a file full of constants with actions:

```
// Actions.ts

export const GET_CUSTOMIZATION_REQUEST = 'GET_CUSTOMIZATION_REQUEST';
export const GET_CUSTOMIZATION_SUCCESS = 'GET_CUSTOMIZATION_SUCCESS';
export const GET_CUSTOMIZATION_FAILURE = 'GET_CUSTOMIZATION_FAILURE';

export const GET_FILES_DATA_SUCCESS = 'GET_FILES_DATA_SUCCESS';
export const TRY_ADD_ATTACHED_DOCUMENT = 'TRY_ADD_ATTACHED_DOCUMENT';

// and more like these lines
```

In the reducer they are used with no typing at all:

```
// Reducer.ts
import { State } from './State.ts';
import * as Actions from './Actions.ts';

export default function Reducer(state: State, action) {
   switch (action.type) {
       case Actions.GET_CUSTOMIZATION_REQUEST:
           // do smth
           return state;
       case Actions.GET_CUSTOMIZATION_SUCCESS:
            // do smth
           return state;
    // and so on

   }
}
```

I want to describe types for some of these actions, and start with a small subset — take that subset and then say something like `type Action = TypedAction | UntypedAction`. To achive it, I'm doing the following, extracting all the constants and excluding typed ones:

```
// ActionsTypes.ts
import * as Actions from './Actions.ts';

export type GetFilesDataSuccessAction = {
    type: typeof Actions.GET_FILES_DATA_SUCCESS;
    payload: boolean;
};

export type TryAddAttachedDocumentAction = {
    type: typeof Actions.TRY_ADD_ATTACHED_DOCUMENT;
    payload: { foo: boolean, bar: boolean };
};

type TypedAction = GetFilesDataSuccessAction | TryAddAttachedDocumentAction;

type TypedActionType = TypedAction['type']; 
// IDE says it's initial type is "GET_FILES_DATA_SUCCESS" | "TRY_ADD_ATTACHED_DOCUMENT"

type UntypedActionTypes = Exclude<keyof typeof Actions, TypedActionType>;
// but this evaluates to never
```

If I "inline" TypedActionType into the declaration of `UntypedActionTypes` like so, it stops being never and works just fine:

```
type UntypedActionTypes = Exclude<keyof typeof Actions, "GET_FILES_DATA_SUCCESS" | "TRY_ADD_ATTACHED_DOCUMENT">;
```

Worth to note, successively omitting the fields from `typeof Actions` worked, but the code starts to look monstrously even with two actions:

```
type UntypedAction = keyof Omit<
    Omit<typeof Actions, GetFilesDataSuccessAction['type']>,
    TryAddAttachedDocumentAction['type']
>;
```

So the quiestion, why does the first option evaluates to `never`, and is there a way to achive needed result without explicitly typing actions' strings or duplicating Omit lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the error by changing `Actions.ts` content from a set of export consts to exporting one const object like so:

```
export const Actions = {
    GET_CUSTOMIZATION_REQUEST: 'GET_CUSTOMIZATION_REQUEST',
    GET_CUSTOMIZATION_SUCCESS: 'GET_CUSTOMIZATION_SUCCESS',
    GET_CUSTOMIZATION_FAILURE: 'GET_CUSTOMIZATION_FAILURE',
    
    GET_FILES_DATA_SUCCESS: 'GET_FILES_DATA_SUCCESS',
    TRY_ADD_ATTACHED_DOCUMENT: 'TRY_ADD_ATTACHED_DOCUMENT',

} as const;
```

And the import ofcourse changed from default to named:

```
import { Actions } from './Actions.ts';
// instead of: import * as Actions from './Actions.ts';
```

Although, still do not understand, why it helps ¯_(ツ)_/¯